# "Using fallback derivation for type ... (derivation: MacroWritersImpl)" warning in Slinky, setState acts weird

Tags: reactjs, scala, scala.js

I'm trying to redo the [TicTacToe tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) for React using [Slinky](https://slinky.dev/).

At some point the game is supposed to remember whose player the turn is. For that, in the tutorial, they add a `xIsNext` boolean. Instead, I defined a

```scala
sealed trait Player { def next: Player }
object Player {
  case object X extends Player { def next: Player = O }
  case object O extends Player { def next: Player = X }
}
```

and the `State` type of the `Board` thus contains a `nextPlayer` field of type `Player`.
When the player clicks, it should update the state by calling `next` on the value of `nextPlayer`.

However, first, when it compiles, I get the warning "Using fallback derivation for type tictactoe.SquareContent.Player (derivation: MacroWritersImpl)" that I don't understand.

Secondly, in the `setState` call, both `nextPlayer` and `nextPlayer.next` are equal to `X`.

I don't have the problem with the boolean way of doing...

How can I fix this?